# How to read particular node from XML data?

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a big XML file having following format.

```
<ESC>
   <ATTRIBUTES>
       < Some sentences of attribute node >
   </ATTRIBUTES>
   <SCRIPT>
       <ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
         <item>***********************************************************.</item>
         <item>* Information.</item>
         <item>***********************************************************.</item>
         <item>* Script for test case : TF_FI_FP_FI_0569_MS07_CO_Search_Help_Internal_Orders_vTD0_1_EN.x</item>
         <item>*</item>
         <item>* For Sub script:</item>
         <item>* 'Test case 3: Choose an Internal Order in One.Fi using external order number while transaction posting (positive case)'.</item>
         <item>*</item>
         <item>* Script is to Display Internal Order using external order number while Transaction Posting 'FB01'</item>
         <item>* GETTAB command is being used to fetch the data from table 'COAS'.           </item>
         <item>*</item>
         <item>*</item>
         <item>* Test data related Information</item>
         <item>* -----------------------------</item>
         <item>* Default test data present in parameter list has been used while Scripting ( script recording & Performing Checks ).</item>
         <item>*</item>
         <item>* Final execution of result log: 0000037077.</item>
         <item>*</item>      
         <item>* Preparation.</item>
         <item/>
         <item/>  <item>**************************************************************************.</item   >
<item>* End Preparation.</item>
<item>********************************************************************************.</item>
<item/>
<item/>
<item>********************************************************************************.</item>
<item>* Execution.</item>
<item>********************************************************************************.</item>
<item>* To get the 'Table Entries' from table 'COAS'.</item>
<item> GETTAB ( COAS , COAS_1 ).</item>
<item>* To display the value for the field 'External Order No'.</item>
<item> LOG ( V_EXTERNAL_ORDER_NO_FRM_TABL ).</item>
<item/>
<item>*----------------------Posting(FB01)-------------------------------------------*.</item>
<item/>
<item>* This part of Script is to Display Internal Order using external order number while Transaction Posting 'FB01'.</item>
<item>MESSAGE ( MSG_1 ).</item>
<item>* To get the name of the Title Screen.</item>
<item> GETGUI ( FB01_100_STEP_1 ).</item>
<item>* Enter the Required details and Press Enter.</item>
<item> SAPGUI ( FB01_100_STEP_2 ).</item>
<item>* Enter Amount and Tax Code.</item>
<item>* and, Press F4 help in the Order Field.</item>
<item> SAPGUI ( FB01_300_STEP_1 ).</item>
<item>* In F4 screen, enter the 'External Order Number'</item>
<item>* pop-up screen is displayed with entries like Order, Description and External Order Number and select 1st order row, press Enter.</item>
<item> SAPGUI ( FB01_200_STEP_1 ).</item>
<item>* To get the values for the field 'Order, Description and External Order No' from F4 help.</item>
<item> GETGUI ( FB01_120_STEP_1 ).</item>
<item>* Press 'Enter' button.</item>
<item> SAPGUI ( FB01_120_STEP_3 ).</item>
<item>* To get the value for the field 'Order' from Main screen.</item>
<item> GETGUI ( FB01_300_STEP_2 ).</item>
<item>* click on 'F3' back button.</item>
<item> SAPGUI ( FB01_300_STEP_3 ).</item>
<item>* click on 'F3' back button.</item>
<item> SAPGUI ( FB01_700_STEP_1 ).</item>
<item>* click 'Yes' button.</item>
<item> SAPGUI ( FB01_200_STEP_2 ).</item>
<item>* click on 'F3' back button.</item>
<item> SAPGUI ( FB01_100_STEP_3 ).</item>
<item>ENDMESSAGE ( E_MSG_1 ).</item>
<item/>
<item>* To display the Title Screen.</item>
<item> LOG ( V_TITLE_SCREEN ).</item>
<item>* To display the 'Order' Number from F4 help.</item>
<item> LOG ( V_ORDER_NO_FROM_F4 ).</item>
<item>* To display the 'Description' from F4 help.</item>
<item> LOG ( V_DESCRIPTION_FROM_F4).</item>
<item>* To display the 'External Order no' value from F4 help.</item>
<item> LOG ( V_EXTERNAL_ORDER_NO_FROM_F4 ).</item>
<item>* To display the 'Order' Number from main screen.</item>
<item> LOG ( V_ORDER_NO_FRM_MAIN_SCREEN ).</item>
<item>********************************************************************************.</item>
<item>* End Execution.</item>
<item>********************************************************************************.</item>
<item/>
<item>********************************************************************************.</item>
<item>* Check.</item>
<item>********************************************************************************.</item>
<item>* To check name of Title screen for transaction FB01.</item>
<item> CHEVAR ( V_TITLE_SCREEN = I_TITLE_SCREEN ).</item>
<item>* To check the value for the field 'External Order No' from F4 help, which should be equal to 'External Order No' from table.</item>
<item> CHEVAR ( V_EXTERNAL_ORDER_NO_FRM_TABL = V_EXTERNAL_ORDER_NO_FROM_F4 ).</item>
<item>* To check the values for the field 'Order' number from Table, which should be equal to 'Order' no from F4 screen and Main screen.</item>
<item> CHEVAR ( ( I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE = V_ORDER_NO_FROM_F4 ) AND ( I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE = V_ORDER_NO_FRM_MAIN_SCREEN )).</item>
<item>*****************************************************************.</item>
<item>* End Check.</item>
<item>******************************************************************.</item>
 </ETXML_LINE_TABTYPE>
 </SCRIPT>
 <PARAMETER>
     <Sentences of PARAMETER tag >
 </PARAMETER>
 </ESC>
```

I want to check above XML using vb script validation criteria as follows.

1. I want to display such line number having no comments (Comments are denoted by line having start symbol `*` and code is denoted by line staring without `*` symbol).
2. In above XML each code had comment just above line of code.
3. So I want to find such line number from XML which code don't have any comment.
4. In short I have to check whether each code having its proper comment or not. If any code having no comment then I have to display error line message.

This is my vb script for above criteria But Firstly I have converted XML to text file and I have worked on text file following is code for text file.

```
filename = "D:\Automation\o.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
fl=0
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
            strLine = f.ReadLine
            if (strLine ="MESSAGE ( MSG_1 ).") then
                      Document.write("<br>Inside MESSAGE ")
                           Do until f.AtEndOfStream
                                            strLine = f.ReadLine
                                             if((Left(strLine,1)="*")) Then
                                                   if((Right(strLine,1)=".")) then 
                                                     Document.write("<br>ERROR Found  at Line No :" & f.line-1&" "& strLine)
                                                   end if
                                                   fl=1
                  else 
                  if((Right(strLine,1)=".") and (fl=1))Then
                     fl=0
                  else
                    Document.write("<br>ERROR Found  at Line No :" & f.line-1&" "& strLine)
                  end if

           end if

  Loop
  end if
```

But now I want Vb script which should follow above mentioned criteria but without converting XML to text file.

Comment: So, what code have you written that you need help with?

Comment: Hello friend, I have mentioned my Vb Script but this code run successfully for text file which has no blank lines. But I have code for XML file which my include blank lines. Thank You in advance.

Comment: SO is not a place where you specify your requirements and other people write code for you. Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx) and come back when you have a specific question about something you can't get to work.